# not sending nested params with the put request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I am working on a rails app with vue on front end. I am making a put request to the server. I am not able. to figure out if there is a way of not sending the nested params with the put request like the location and numbers. I just want to send the agency_unique_number and name params on the submitAgency request. Please help me find a way.

```
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
    agency: {
      name: '',
      location: {
       street: ''
       city:''
       province:''
      }
      numbers: {
       office_number: '',
       fax_number: ''
      }
      agency_unique_number: ''
    }
  }
  method: {
    submitAgency() {
      this.$axios.put('/agency.json', { agency: this.agency })
      .then(response => {
      })
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using PUT? Are your trying to update the created record?

Comment: @aleksa_95 yes thats right. I am updating a created record.

Comment: Did you checked headers in Chrome DevTool? Is there data with nested fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply extract the data you want to send.

```js
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
    agency: {
      name: '',
      location: {
       street: ''
       city:''
       province:''
      }
      numbers: {
       office_number: '',
       fax_number: ''
      }
      agency_unique_number: ''
    }
  }
  method: {
    submitAgency() {
      const { agency_unique_number, name } = this.agency
      const data = { agency_unique_number, name }

      this.$axios.put('/agency.json', { agency: data  })
      .then(response => {
      })
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try again with

```js
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
    agency: {
      name: '',
      location: {
       street: ''
       city:''
       province:''
      }
      numbers: {
       office_number: '',
       fax_number: ''
      }
      agency_unique_number: ''
    }
  }
  method: {
    submitAgency() {
      const { name, agency_unique_number } = this.agency
      this.$axios.put('/agency.json', { agency: { name, agency_unique_number })
      .then(response => {
      })
    },
  }
}
```